# How to know group level in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, environments, expl3

Sometimes I have cases when `\everypar` calls in other group level than before. For example, `\everypar` calls inside document, but the second time it calls inside `\xalignat` environment.

Is there an existing variable in `expl3` which allows us to know the group level to compare it inside `\everypar` command? If not, how to solve it for all environments?

Maybe I should redefine `\bgroup` and `\egroup` commands, and increase or decrease my own variable connected with the group level? If yes, how it do correct?

Comment: Please clarify: `{A}{B}{C}\bgroup D\egroup\bgroup E\egroup\bgroup F\egroup` -- `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` are not in the same group. Are they to be considered in the same group-level ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The etex primitive `\currentgrouplevel` holds the group nesting level.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Where i can find all latex variables,usefull for each other?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy this is a primitive not latex-defined, these are documented in the texbook or the manuals for etex, xetex, luatex etc. so in this case `texdoc etex`